# Android: Adding a delay to the display of toast?

Tags: android, toast

I wish to display a `toast` if a certain condition is `true` or `false`. However I want this toast to `delay` for `two seconds` before it is displayed.

How can I do this?

**Current if statement:**

```
if (result.equals("true")) {

                        loginDataBaseAdapter.updateUploadedRecord(sessionId);

                            Toast.makeText(MathsGameResults.this,
                                    "Data is successfully uploaded.",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(
                                    MathsGameResults.this,
                                    "Error while uploading. Please try again later.",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }

                    }
```

Comment: @james Thread.sleep() freezes the UI. You have to use handler

Answer (score 9):

Try this..

Use [`Handler`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html)

```
            // Handler which will run after 2 seconds.
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                      Toast.makeText(MathsGameResults.this,
                                "Data is successfully uploaded.",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }, 2000);
```

Comment: When I attempt this i get the error: No enclosing instance of the type MathsGameResults is accessible in scope

Comment: @user3968848 Are you using that in `Fragment` or `Activity`?

Comment: in activity, not in fragment

Answer (score 0):

Delaying the code might not always work successfully especially on devices with a low RAM. Here is what you can do.

Define this variable

```
boolean result;
```

Add this code at end of `loginDataBaseAdapter` code if the data is successfully uploaded

```
result = true;
showResult(result);
```

Then add this method -

```
public void showResult(boolean i){

    if (result == true;) {

        loginDataBaseAdapter.updateUploadedRecord(sessionId);

        Toast.makeText(
                          MathsGameResults.this,
                          "Data is successfully uploaded.",
                          Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                      ).show();

    } else {

        Toast.makeText(
                       MathsGameResults.this,
                       "Error while uploading. Please try again later.",
                       Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                      ).show();
    }         
}
```

Anyways here is how to delay the code -

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            if (result == true;) {

                loginDataBaseAdapter.updateUploadedRecord(sessionId);

                Toast.makeText(
                                MathsGameResults.this,
                                "Data is successfully uploaded.",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                              ).show();

            } else {

                Toast.makeText(
                               MathsGameResults.this,
                               "Error while uploading. Please try again later.",
                               Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                              ).show();
           }

        }
}, 5000);
```