# how to delay a toast message in android

Tags: java, android

i want delay a toast message for 20 seconds so this is my code

```
 b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button4);
b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Welcome to my first project in android",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
});
```

layout

```
    <Button
    android:id="@+id/button4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button"
    android:layout_marginTop="67dp"
    android:text="About" />
```

so how can i do it ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android: Adding a delay to the display of toast?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25461791/android-adding-a-delay-to-the-display-of-toast)

Answer (score 1):

To do that, you can use a `Handler` and the `postDelayed()` method:

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
     handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
  Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Welcome to my first project in android",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}, 20000); //in milliseconds

});
```

Comment: This will not work from Android 8 to Android 10. Still I am not able to figure out the reason. I works from Android 11.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done by using Handler method.

```
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            //your code here
        }
    },5000); // will trigger your code after 5 seconds
```